# Having trouble getting AWS Lambda to send prompt message to Lex

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to make a template to write new functions for AWS Lambda to validate input from Lex. I am not having any trouble with fulfilling correct inputs, only in getting Lex to relay the prompt messages when the slots are incorrectly filled.

```
def hello_world(intent_request):
    object_of_greeting = get_slots(intent_request)["HelloObject"]
    type_of_greeting = get_slots(intent_request)["GreetingType"]
    # add more of these calls if more slots are involved
    
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']

    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # Perform basic validation on the supplied input slot(s).
        # Use the elicitSlot dialog action to re-prompt for the first violation detected.
        slots = get_slots(intent_request)

        validation_result = validate_greeting(object_of_greeting, type_of_greeting)
        if not validation_result['isValid']:
            slots[validation_result['violatedSlot']] = None
            return elicit_slot(intent_request['sessionAttributes'],
                               intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                               slots,
                               validation_result['violatedSlot'],
                               validation_result['message'])
```

Etc... Then, the validation function:

```
def validate_greeting(object_of_greeting, type_of_greeting):
    
    objects = ['world', 'kitty', 'my dear']
    # these should match the listed examples of their corresponding slot, which is 'HelloObject' here
    if object_of_greeting is not None and object_of_greeting.lower() not in objects:
        return build_validation_result(False,
                                       'HelloObject',
                                       f'You cannot greet {object_of_greeting}, 
                                       would you like to greet someone else?')

    greetings = ['hello', "gday", "whassup"]
    if type_of_greeting is not None and type_of_greeting.lower() not in greetings:
        return build_validation_result(False,
                                       'GreetingType',
                                       f'You cannot say {type_of_greeting} to anyone. 
                                       How about gday or whassup?')

    return build_validation_result(True, None, None)
```

I am able to return a correct JSON with a test script for the `build_validation_result` function, like the following:

```
{
  'isValid': False, 
  'violatedSlot': 'HelloObject', 
  'message': {
      'contentType': 'PlainText', 
      'content': 'You cannot greet foobar, would you like to greet someone else?
  }
}
```

I have also written a Lambda test for false inputs, which gives the following response:

```
{
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "dialogAction": {
    "type": "ElicitSlot",
    "intentName": "HelloWorld",
    "slots": {
      "HelloObject": null,
      "GreetingType": "howdy"
    },
    "slotToElicit": "HelloObject",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": "You cannot greet foobar, would you like to greet someone else?"
    }
  }
}
```

Somehow, the validation result isn't making its way back to Lex, and so it's only returning the console prompt, 'Who would you like to greet?' over and over before giving up after n-attempts.

My testing suggests that the correct JSONs are being output from the Lambda function, so I don't know why I can never get their prompt messages to appear in the chat bot. Any help much appreciated. Will post more details if required.

Comment: To add to the confusion, I've found that with two slots that need filling, I can get the Lambda prompt when trying ElicitSlot for second priority slot, but not the first.